# What are the downsides of having a bigger dead zone?

Tags: controllers

I have a Xbox 360 controller and it has always worked fine on PC and Xbox 360.

I then used in on Switch, even though the calibration shows a slight drift to the left, I still played Xenoblade Chronicles using it and experienced no drift. I then played Zelda and the drift starts to appear. This led me to believe that maybe Zelda has a higher sensitity, and the issue can be resolved software-wise by lowering the sensitivity - having a bigger dead zone on the joystick.

There must be some reason why the option of increasing the dead zone was not considered by console makers who do have this issue. What would be the downsides of increasing the dead zone?

Comment: Hi lulalala, I reframed your question slightly to try and keep it on topic -- the previous phrasing focused a little much on developer intent, which is off-topic on Arqade. Please feel free to make further edits if I haven't effectively captured what you'd like to know :)

Comment: @Schism thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bigger dead zone means less of active zone, and the active zone being more distant. More time until the joystick reacts, harder to find the point where it starts reacting (stop -> slow walk), harder to fine-tune the 'active' angle (e.g. normal walk / light jog vs full sprint), and in the end it doesn't fully solve the drift problem as in a worn joystick turn left can be much closer to the 'inert' position than turn right, the joystick stopping at an edge of the dead zone, not in the center.

In the perfect world, there would be no dead zone at all - the joystick would stop exactly in the center every single time, and merest touch would result in weakest non-zero signal. But in the real world, wear, drift, imprecision, even our own shaky hands need to be dealt with, and the dead zone is a crutch, a method to drown all these inaccuracies. The smaller it is the more responsive the joystick, the finer control possible for the player. So it's set as result of in-depth usability studies, a precarious balance, a middle ground between sinking shortcomings of the joystick and providing a good response.

...and if the joystick gets too worn and the dead zone ceases to suffice - oh, this is also a precarious balance, a subject of in-depth business studies. Sales of replacement accessories is a big source of income for console manufacturers, but make the accessory too crappy and you face a class action lawsuit, recall and bad reviews, so the dead zone must be set just so that the drift won't infuriate too many customers too soon.